# SDL + Mac OS X issue (window not responsive to keystrokes in certain situations)

Tags: c, macos, clang, sdl

I was trying to play around a bit with SDL on macOS (High Sierra 10.13.2) and I stumbled on what seems to be a rather incomprehensible mistake involving SDL windows not responding to keystrokes. I tried to construct two minimally different examples demarcating when this problem occurs: in fact, the examples do differ so minimally that it seems bizarre that their behaviour differs at all.

I have version 1.2.15 of the SDL libraries installed, and they were installed using the 'brew install sdl' command.

The first example (the one that does work correctly) is as follows:

```
/* sdl1.c */

#include "SDL/SDL.h"

SDL_Surface *screen;
SDL_Event event;

void initsdl (void) {
    SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode (500, 250, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    SDL_EnableKeyRepeat (SDL_DEFAULT_REPEAT_DELAY, SDL_DEFAULT_REPEAT_INTERVAL);
    while (1)
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                    break;
    SDL_Quit ();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    initsdl ();
    return 0;
}
```

The other example is almost identical, but is spread over two files.

```
/* sdl2a.c */

#include "SDL/SDL.h"

SDL_Surface *screen;
SDL_Event event;

void initsdl (void) {
    SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode (500, 250, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    SDL_EnableKeyRepeat (SDL_DEFAULT_REPEAT_DELAY, SDL_DEFAULT_REPEAT_INTERVAL);
    while (1)
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                    break;
    SDL_Quit ();
}
```

With the second file being:

```
/* sdl2b.c */

void initsdl(void);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    initsdl ();
    return (0);
}
```

As you can see, these programs are close to identical, with the only real difference being the fact that one of them is spread out over two files.

Now, I compile these files with the commands

```
cc -Wall -o sdl1 sdl1.c `sdl-config --libs` # (1)
```

and

```
cc -Wall -o sdl2 sdl2a.c sdl2b.c `sdl-config --libs` # (2)
```

I get two differences in the resulting behaviour.

First of all, the first example does not give any warnings whatsoever, whereas the second example gives the following warning:

```
ld: warning: object file (/usr/local/lib/libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)) was built for newer OSX version (10.13) than being linked (10.12)
```

The second difference is more problematic, however. Whereas the first example (the one who *does* give a compiler warning) behaves as it should, with a window appearing on screen, which correctly responds to the pressing of the ESC key before quitting, the second example simply *does not respond* to keystrokes at all, even after clicking on the window to make it active. This result is obtained by executing the binary resulting from the compilation directly from the terminal.

Comment: Your `main` file does not have `#include "SDL/SDL.h"`, which on some platforms does `#define main SDLmain`, and you're supposed to link with `libSDLmain` that implements actual entry point, performs initial setup, and calls `SDLmain`.